# Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0 destroys project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have an old application written with VC++ 6.0, that I have to maintain. The application is quite large, and it would require a lot of time to convert it to a newer VC++ (like VS2005).

The problem is, that every time I make the smallest changes in the code, the solution (.dsw-file) is destroyed.

I use a VMware Virtual Machine running Windows XP 32bit as Development Environment.

Has anyone else experienced the same problem with Microsoft Visual C++ 6.0?

Comment: Possibly a manually-edited .dsw file? Have you tried to diff the "destroyed" file vs. the original one to find out exactly *what* is "destroyed"? That information might help enormously.

Comment: "it would require a lot of time to convert it" are you sure? Have you tried? In a lot of cases it's just a matter of creating a new project, settings some compiler/linker options and adding all source files.

Comment: Making a new project instead of limping along with some patched up old project is the right thing to do.

Comment: @stijn not to forget fix any non-standardconformant code that gets compiled by that dinosaur and not by newer versions. However, it's worth a try.

Comment: Once you open it in a newer version, the project conversion wizard in visual studio pops up and it will be easily converted to the newer version by pressing next button. I have done it in vs2008. To make it compile you have give the proper project settings by adding the paths to lib and include files

Comment: Might I advertise the use of [CMake](http://www.cmake.org)? One configuration file, which CMake can turn into project files for Visual Studio [6,7,8,9,10,11], CodeBlocks, KDevelop, Eclipse, NMake / Unix Makefiles... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to give advice, VS6 is not well known to spontaneously destruct project files.  You could arbitrarily set the read-only attribute on the .dsw file, you ought to get some kind of message when whatever code is doing this finds out it can no longer delete the file.

I have to add some unwelcome advice.  Using a grossly outdated version of Visual Studio is okayish, but as time ticks on the inconveniences and quirks build up.  It never gets better.  Until you get to a point where investing the time to update the project (don't pick the grossly outdated VS2005) gets to be competitive with the amount of time you waste keeping the old one going.  Sounds like D-day has arrived.  Time to ditch it.

Comment: Ok. The unwelcome advice is quite welcome. The fact is, that it requires a lot of time to upgrade the project. I was just trying to use the "tools" I have on hand. I have tried to convert to project to VS2005 manually, but this resulted in a lot of problems with debugging, and I couldn't even start the application.